# On Linux (CentOS 5), remembering when we've followed a symlink and being about to 'cd ..' out again

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh, symbolic-link

I'm trying to figure out how to tell the shell (tcsh) to remember when I've gone into a symlinked folder, and allow 'cd ..' to navigate back out of the symlink rather than just navigate to the parent directory of the linked-to folder...

For example:

```
$ ls -al /jobs
tech -> /mnt/projects1/tech
temp -> /mnt/projects2/temp

$ cd /jobs/tech
$ cd ../temp
../temp: No such file or directory.

$ pwd
/mnt/projects1/tech
```

Any idea how to do this? I have a feeling that it's a shell setting that you can set somewhere....

Cheers

Comment: updated my answer to  be probably more what you're looking for...haven't tested it yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't have to do it for more than one "step" you could use `cd -` instead

**so it looks like setting the symlink env variable to ignore might get your desired response**
from the man page:

> symlinks (+)
>   Can be set to several different values to control symbolic link
>   ('symlink') resolution:
>
> If  set to 'chase', whenever the current directory changes to a
>   directory containing a symbolic link, it  is  expanded  to  the
>   real name of the directory to which the link points.  This does
>   not work for the user's home directory; this is a bug.
>
> If set to 'ignore', the shell  tries  to  construct  a  current
>   directory relative to the current directory before the link was
>   crossed.  This means that cding through  a  symbolic  link  and
>   then  'cd  ..'ing  returns one to the original directory.  This
>   affects only builtin commands and filename completion.
>
> If set to 'expand', the shell tries to fix  symbolic  links  by
>   actually  expanding arguments which look like path names.  This
>   affects any command, not just  builtins.   Unfortunately,  this
>   does  not  work  for hard-to-recognize filenames, such as those
>   embedded in command options.  Expansion  may  be  prevented  by
>   quoting.  While this setting is usually the most convenient, it
>   is sometimes misleading and sometimes confusing when  it  fails
>   to  recognize  an argument which should be expanded.  A compro-
>   mise is to use `ignore' and use the editor  command  normalize-
>   path (bound by default to ^X-n) when necessary.

Comment: That's been my method so far, but it's not an ideal workflow...

Comment: I think we both found the same answer at the same time there! :D

Comment: looks like, give yourself the check

Comment: Nah, it's yours... I should have done a search through the manpage before posting on here in the first place... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've just managed to answer my own question here, at least for tcsh, anyway...

On the tcsh manpage, it talks about the 'symlinks' variable...

So, I can now do:

```
$ set symlinks=expand

$ cd /jobs/tech
$ pwd
/mnt/projects1/tech
$ echo $cwd
/jobs/tech

$ cd ..
$ echo $cwd
/jobs
```

Because of all of this, I'm quite tempted to just alias pwd to 'echo $cwd', as it'll give the user a more accurate view of where they can consider themselves to be in the filesystem...